# Public API for iOS music player?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, mpmusicplayercontroller

Is there any way I can access music playing in the native iOS music app? For example on button press in *my* app it pauses the built in Music app. I've tried MPMusicPlayerController but that doesn't seem to be what I want; or I'm not using it correctly.

This is what I've tried.

```
    if ([musicPlayer playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
            [musicPlayer pause];
    } else {
            [musicPlayer play];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you instantiate your music player. To get access to the system global payer you should use:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
```

Be aware that if you're using `applicationMusicPlayer` it will only work for your application and pausing music will not affect the music playing in your Music.app.

See the [MPMusicPlayerController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008221-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) overview section for a more extensive description of the two.